# Why does this.classList.toggle("classname") affect parents of this as well?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a website and I'm having some trouble with javascript. I have this function:

```
function offerboxclick(obj) {
    obj.classList.toggle("menuelementclicked");
}
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<div class="menuelement" onclick="offerboxclick(this)">
    <div class="arrowbox">
            <div class="stripe1"></div>
            <div class="stripe2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menutext">Menu level 0</div>
    <level>
        <div class="menuelement" onclick="offerboxclick(this)">
            <div class="arrowbox">
                    <div class="stripe1"></div>
                    <div class="stripe2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="menutext">Menu level 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="menuelement" onclick="offerboxclick(this)">
            <div class="arrowbox">
                    <div class="stripe1"></div>
                    <div class="stripe2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="menutext">Menu level 1</div>
        </div>
    </level>
</div>

<div class="menuelement" onclick="offerboxclick(this)">
    <div class="arrowbox">
            <div class="stripe1"></div>
            <div class="stripe2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menutext">Menu level 0</div>

</div>
```

The css code I think isn't relevant, because the problem is probably with the js function. As you can see, I have a multi level menu, and it works just fine when I'm clicking on the level 0 element to show hidden level 1 elements. But when I click any of the level 1 elements, the js function does work properly on the object, because it toggles "menuelementclicked" class on it. The problem is that it also toggles this class in parent menu element, so at the same time it opens level 2 and closes whole menu. I don't really know what to do now. Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. I tried putting my code on jsfiddle to show you all of it but for some reason on it doesn't work there at all 0_o

Comment: You need to `stopPropagation`: `onclick="offerboxclick.call(this,event);"` and `function offerboxclick(event) { this.classList.toggle('menuelementclicked'); event.stopPropagation(); }`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol
Thanks a lot! It works perfectly now :)